# Angular 9 - router.navigate not firing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

When my App initializes, it calls a service that checks to ensure the user has properly configured their profile. If the profile is not configured, I redirect the user to the profile screen. This call is made from the service itself.

For some reason, my call to `router.navigate` is failing. What are some possible reasons to explain why `router.navigate` fails to do anything?

Here is how I make the call. Does the syntax look ok?

`this.router.navigate(['profile', 'init']);`

Here is my app.

### app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then((m) => m.ProfileModule) },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/account', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ] },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

### app.component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private profileInitService: ProfileInitService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.profileInitService.checkProfile();
  }
}
```

### profile.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'init',
        component: ProfileInitComponent,
        data: ProfileInitComponent.stepData
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

### profile.service

```
export class ProfileService {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {

  }

  checkProfile() {

    // FETCH ACCOUNT INFO

    // THEN

    // if account info incomplete {
      console.log('profile incomplete');
      this.router.navigate(['profile', 'init']);
    }
  }
}
```

My console.log is firing, but not the call to router.navigate. Could  the way I have my routes set up be the reason why I cannot bounce the user to the profile/init page?

Comment: Does it work if you change `path: ''` to `path: 'profile'` in `profile.module`? And do you get any error when you do like you have?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are facing an issue with lazy-loading and relative routes.

Your `ProfileComponent` is configured on the route `profile`:

app.routing

```
 ...
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module')...
```

profile.module

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
    ...
```

As your `ProfileComponent` is [lazzy loaded](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#forroot-and-forchild) it does not use the [root injector](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection). This means the router service from your lazy-loaded module is in a different context from the one in the other modules...

When you execute `this.router.navigate(['profile','init'])` from `ProfileComponent` it tries to go to `profile\profile\init`.

if you enable tracing on the root route, you might get to see this happening:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  enableTracing: true, // <== this setting should not be enabled in prod
  ...
  })
```

To fix the navigation issue you should change it to relative navigation, using use the current route as base:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ...

this.router.navigate(['init'], { relativeTo: this.route })
```

or use a  `/` to impose absolute navigation:

```
this.router.navigate(['/profile','init'])
```